# How to use .less file in asp.net core?

Tags: css, asp.net-core, less

In our website we have HTML snippet included in a page.

In HTML snippet we have used the bootstrap 4 classes like col-lg-4, row etc.

The reference of css file of bootstrap is included in HTML snippet only, and because of that, the design of page in which HTML snippet is included get affected because of bootstrap.

The HTML snippet is rendered in specific div element having class "property-details", can we do something like the bootstrap css will only be applied on the content inside the "property-details" and not for the whole site?

The Website is in ASP.NET Core.

We tried to solve the issue by following the solution mentioned at : https://basementmedia.no/2015/01/19/how-to-use-bootstrap-or-other-css-frameworks-on-a-small-part-of-a-page-without-affecting-the-rest-of-the-pages-style/

But I do not know how to use .less file in ASP.NET Core, is there any solution ?

Comment: Use a vs tool (or webpack) to compile your less and then add your compiled file to your bundle - unless your tool minimises too, then you can just put a link to the compiled css file.  This is a popular compiler: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler

Comment: Ypu can also use compilation theough a browser. `<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" /><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js" ></script>` Look [on site](http://lesscss.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with extension .less (test.less).
In visual studio marketplace search for LESS Compiler. Download and install LESS Compiler.

Open your less file in visual studio 
[image]

click on thing mention in the bottom right corner or opened file to switch on/off less pre-compilation to css